# XCode 7: Copy Layoutattributes

Tags: swift2, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm getting the warning "This is likely occurring because the flow layout subclass MyApp.MenuFlowLayout is modifying attributes returned by UICollectionViewFlowLayout without copying them". How can I copy this in Swift?

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

    if let array = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect) as [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        var visibleRect = CGRectZero
        visibleRect.origin = (self.collectionView?.contentOffset)!
        visibleRect.size = (self.collectionView?.bounds.size)!


        let activeDisatance : CGFloat = visibleRect.size.width / 2
        let zoomFactor : CGFloat = 0.15

        for attributes in array{
            if CGRectIntersectsRect(attributes.frame, visibleRect){
                let distance  = CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect) - attributes.center.x
                let normalizedDistance = distance / activeDisatance
                if abs(distance) < activeDisatance{
                    let zoom = 1 + zoomFactor * (1 - abs(normalizedDistance))
                    attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeScale(zoom, zoom, 1.0)
                    attributes.zIndex = 1
                }
            }
        }
        return array
    }
    return super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Collections in Swift are value types, that's the reason why they don't have a `copy()` method. So when you are calling

```
array = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect) as [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?
```

it already creates a copy of the super layout attributes array and stores it in `array`

The problem is not that the array has not been copied, the problem is, that you are changing the `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` inside the array without copying them first.

To avoid this error message you can do something like this:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)
    var attributesCopy = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    for itemAttributes in attributes! {
        let itemAttributesCopy = itemAttributes.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
        // add the changes to the itemAttributesCopy                       
        attributesCopy.append(itemAttributesCopy)
    }

    return attributesCopy
}
```